# How do I access GUI-Elements in another thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In C#: How do I access GUI-Elements, like buttons or labels in another thread?

Comment: WinForms? WPF? MonoTouch? Silverlight?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Threading and GUI elements in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535266/threading-and-gui-elements-in-c)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `Invoke`, like this:

```
Invoke((MethodInvoker)(()=>lblName.Text="Meep"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't.

Instead, you need to call `Invoke` or `BeginInvoke` to execute code on the UI thread.