# Thread update main screen via event

Tags: c#, multithreading, events

I am trying to get a thread to update a GUI and i was advised to use an event.

Specifically the application gives me a cross threading error in the method UpdateResult() below.
I assume the event i raise is being raised from the thread and hence the issue as it is trying to update the GUI which runs on the main thread.

What have i done incorrectly?

thanks
Damo

**C# Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
public delegate void UpdateScreenEventHandler();
namespace EventHandler
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public static event UpdateScreenEventHandler _UpdateScreen;



        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // Add event handlers to Show event.
            _UpdateScreen += new UpdateScreenEventHandler(UpdateResult);

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Thread the status check
            Thread trd = new Thread(() => Threadmethod());
            trd.IsBackground = true;
            trd.Start();

        }

        private void Threadmethod()
        {
            // Invoke the event.
            _UpdateScreen.Invoke();
        }

        private void UpdateResult()
        {
            textBox1.Text = "This Is the result";
            MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Obligatory suggestion to read [Joe Albahari's excellent and free ebook](http://www.albahari.com/threading/)

Comment: I had a similar problem and found this article to be very helpful http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/449594/Progress-Bars-Threads-Windows-Forms-and-You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event is fired from a background thread, so you need to marshal to the UI thread if you want to access UI elements from the event handler.

```
private void UpdateResult()
{
    textBox1.Invoke(new Action( ()=>
    {
        textBox1.Text = "This Is the result";
        MessageBox.Show(textBox1.Text);
    });
}
```

Another option would be to fire the event in the UI thread so that the event handlers won't need to do it.

```
private void Threadmethod()
{
    Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        // Invoke the event.
        _UpdateScreen.Invoke();
    });
}
```

Comment: ok - that makes sense - but why was i told to use the event handler in the first place? "RULE: You should not access one window from another thread.

Use this technique:

from your thread raise an event to update the RTF (with required text etc data)
on the GUI thread use the following:
use .... @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535266/threading-and-gui-elements-in-c-sharp

Comment: I think `BeginInvoke` would be preferable here, unless it needs to be synchronous.

Comment: @JonB Potentially.  If the BG thread isn't doing anything after firing the even then you're not holding it up, so it shouldn't be a big difference either way.

Comment: @Servy - your second suggestion is perfect. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Your setting the textbox on the same thread. Call this from your event.

```
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.
        if (this.textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        {   
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
```

This is as per the following MSDN link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: ok - that makes sense - but why was i told to use the event handler in the first place? "RULE: You should not access one window from another thread. Use this technique: from your thread raise an event to update the RTF (with required text etc data) on the GUI thread use the following: use .... @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535266/threading-and-gui-elements-in-c-sharp

Comment: @user1438082 You don't have to use the event handler. You can call this directly from where you raise the event and pass a string variable.

Comment: yes and i have have done that in the past but is the user on stack incorrect when he says to use an eventhandler - i dont now understand why i would use an event handler?

Comment: @user1438082 You should probably ask them.  You haven't provided enough information here, although it does seem appropriate to me to use an event.

Comment: The code here is needlessly complex.  You *know* you're not in the UI thread, so there's no need to check it.  Just call `Invoke` unconditionally and avoid the pointless check and recursive call.  Honestly, it's a poor pattern that rarely, if ever, should be used.  You should always know if some code is going to be run in the UI thread or not, you shouldn't need to be checking.

Comment: @Servy indeed it is and probably should be a lot less complex, if the OP clicks `Get help for this exception` in Visual Studio or googles the problem you will find the solution above because that's what MSDN states - albeit long winded, I didn't see the point in spending more of my time shortening the code when I could just C+P and still help the user :)

Comment: See, in this case the code is so short and simple I find that typing a *proper* answer to be *faster* than googing the problem, finding an MSDN page, taking a less appropriate answer, adapting it to fit the question, and then posting that, but I guess that's just me.  I'm too lazy to go out of my way to provide poorer quality answers.

Comment: @Servy I apologise for not having as good answering skills/on the spot coding skills as you, oh mighty Servy...

Comment: Well according to your previous post you were just to lazy to do it, not incapable of doing it.  Quality matters, particularly when your providing an answer to a common solution to someone who's very likely to continue using that solution.  Even if it did take you a bit longer to write a proper solution, you should have done so.